# Changing c++ for loop into x86

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

currently i am learning x86 assembly as one of my uni modules, i have a program written in c++ which takes a string of 6 characters and encrypts them based on an encryption key.

the code for encrypt_chars :

```
void encrypt_chars(int length, char EKey)
{
    char temp_char;                     // char temporary store
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // encrypt characters one at a time
    {
        temp_char = OChars[i];          //
        __asm {                         //
            push eax
            push ecx
            lea eax, EKey
            push temp_char
            push eax
            call encrypt21
            mov temp_char, al
            add esp, 8
            pop ecx
            pop eax
        }

    EChars[i] = temp_char;          // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array
    }
return;
}
```

i would love some help on how to change the for loop at the top of the code into assembly language, thank you.

Comment: You can simply watch the disassembly code through the debugger (and you may as well change your entire code to C++ beforehand, and let the compiler turn it into assembly).

Comment: The `-S` option to GCC or Clang will give you the generated assembly. You can use that to figure out how to write a for loop in x86 assembly. This technique is generally useful for learning assembly, write some C code and let the compiler teach you how to write it in asm!

Comment: You forgot to include the declaration of EChars and OChars. Post them.

Answer (score 0):

Read about jmp and reading variables byte after byte with saving to registers. I will give you example, you could read  variable like that var(,%esi,4) where var is name of yor variable, esi is incremented register, 4 is how long is your word. Look at Intel documentation